# What happens if more than one boy/girl volunteers as tribute?

Tags: the-hunger-games

The Career Tributes from Districts 1, 2, and 4 volunteer for the right to compete in the Hunger Games. What happens if more than one boy or girl volunteers to compete? Say four boys from District 1 all say at the same time "I volunteer as tribute". What happens then? Do they just have a drawing between those four?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68559/can-a-chosen-tribute-decline-a-volunteer-taking-their-place

Comment: Cage fight to the death, presumably.